# Opeing trainer similar to Chesstempo?

Tags: training

Is there a similar web site that teaches Openings like [Chesstempo.com](https://chesstempo.com) in a sense that you can train and verify lines, etc. I find the Chesstempo user interface confusing and overal user experience isn't satisfactory, so I'm looking for alternatives.

Comment: someone has created https://www.studyopenings.com/ . not sure if it fits ur needs

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not exactly in the same direction, I like the courses of Chessable, they allow to train openings by repetition, and I find the tool very intuitive to use.
They have quite a few free courses. Check it out: https://www.chessable.com/

Comment: +1, but I'd add that the "verification of lines" part isn't convenient on Chessable. They only provide a slow, shallow engine running in you local browser and you can't easily get the variations out of Chessable to analyze with a local Stockfish (this is even against the terms of use..)